# erl_publish failing with partial packet

Tags: erlang, erl, cnode

I am having a strange problem trying to bring up a C-Node Server. I am following the example from http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/cnode.html.

I found that I would fail at

```
if (erl_publish(port) == -1)
erl_err_quit("erl_publish");
```

Running epmd in debug mode showed the following message after the failure:

```
got partial packet only on file descriptor 4 (0)
```

gdb showed that the application was getting an error in epmd_publish.c when checking for a valid response.

```
 if (((res=get8(s)) != EI_EPMD_ALIVE2_RESP))
```

Have you seen this before? Do I have something configured in the system wrong? I am so confused.